# TV series involving a man with some electricity superpower but who suffers from severe headaches

Tags: story-identification, tv, super-hero

I'm looking for the name of a TV series, probably from the 80s or early 90s, involving people with superpowers.

In particular, I remember a man who can shoot lightning from his hands (similar to the Emperor's Force lightning power in Star Wars, and to Elle Bishop's power in Heroes).

However, he seems to be suffering from very severe headaches (possibly caused by the use of his powers) that almost completely incapacitates him, to the point that he can't walk on his own (I also remember a woman helping him to walk).

Any idea?

Comment: "80's show" + "Guy with lightning power" leads me to guess Misfits of Science. The rest I don't remember. The second part makes me think of Highlander (they're always somewhat incapacitated while being struck by lightning after winning a battle - but they're not in control of the lightning so that's probably not it)

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking for this show for the longest time. Thanks to you and google, my child shows are now complete. The other was the cartoon series, Let's Go Ghostbusters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Misfits of Science had a guy with lightning power. And [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_of_Science) even mentions a writer connection to Heroes.

> Mark Thomas Miller stars as Johnny "Johnny B" Bukowski, a
>   rock-and-roll musician who was electrocuted on stage, thus giving him
>   formidable electrical powers. He continually drains any electrically
>   charged items in his surroundings, forcing him to live in isolation.
>   He wears sunglasses because his eyes glow when he is fully charged. He
>   can hurl lightning bolts and run at superhuman speed, easily outracing
>   in one episode a parody of the Six Million Dollar Man, but he is
>   vulnerable to water which short circuits him and burns his flesh. He
>   is a big Chuck Berry fan, in the pilot singing "Johnny B. Goode" when
>   he goes into battle.