# Short series about teenager that could move fast

Tags: story-identification

As a kid (somewhere in the eighties) I remember a short series, twelve episodes or so about a teen that was hit by lightning and could move extremely fast after that. It was like time slowed down for him.

There was also a Doc Brown kind of character.

I tried looking for it online, but no idea of the title. Does anybody know?

Comment: This sounds like a synopsis of Flash!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a chance you're remembering "[My Secret Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Secret_Identity)", which lasted three seasons with 24 episodes each season, but as it was syndicated (in the US and other countries) it's possible any particular station you watched it on decided to stop carrying it or moved it to an inconvenient time.

In it, Andrew (Jerry O'Connell) is a teenager who has a very Marty/Doc Brown type relationship with his next door neighbor, a scientist, especially after one day, while visiting he gets caught in the beam of one of the Doc's inventions, which grants him super powers, including invulnerability, the ability to float (he needed aerosol cans to do more, at least at first), and, more germane to your question, super speed.

Answer (score 2):

[Misfits of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_of_Science)

> Mark Thomas Miller as Johnny "Johnny B" Bukowski, a rock-and-roll musician **who was electrocuted on stage**, thus giving him formidable electrical powers. He continually drains any electrically charged items in his surroundings, forcing him to live in isolation. He wears sunglasses because his eyes glow when he is fully charged. He can hurl lightning bolts **and run at superhuman speed**, easily outracing in one episode a parody of the Six Million Dollar Man, but he is vulnerable to water which short circuits him and burns his flesh. He is a big Chuck Berry fan, in the pilot singing "Johnny B. Goode" when he goes into battle.

It's **always** *Misfits Of Science*.

[TV Pilot or Movie, 80s, misfit team with powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223058/tv-pilot-or-movie-80s-misfit-team-with-powers)

[TV series involving a man with some electricity superpower but who suffers from severe headaches](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64275/tv-series-involving-a-man-with-some-electricity-superpower-but-who-suffers-from/64318#64318)

[Kids show from the early 2000’s with a blonde teen that would turn into an electric superhero](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241417/kids-show-from-the-early-2000-s-with-a-blonde-teen-that-would-turn-into-an-elect/241767#241767)

Comment: Well, this time it wasn't Misfits of Science :-). @starpilotsix' answer of My Secret Identity was correct.